# How to change graph vertex color without having to manually input each vertex change?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Using the following code I can create a graph which is just a visual depiction of `SA`.

```
SA = SparseArray[_ :> RandomInteger[1], {10, 10}]
lis1 = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"}
lis2 = RandomSample[lis1, 4]
AGSA = AdjacencyGraph[lis1, SA, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]]
```

I would like to change the color of some of the vertices, the vertices I want to change colors of are given by `lis2`.  I'm looking for a way to change the vertex color without having to manually change each color individually (For instance, I could look at the results given by `lis2` and create a new AGSA with the additional inclusion of `VertexStyle -> {"A" -> Blue, "C" -> Blue,...}`, where each vertex labeled is just manually pulled from lis2}, but that is quite time consuming and unrealistic for much larger graphs.  Is there a way to perform the desired vertex transformation without having to just manually change each individual vertex?

Comment: Can't you just add the option: `VertexStyle -> Thread[lis2 -> Blue]` to your AdjacencyGraph call?

Comment: Wow I completely overthought it, thank you, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use rules with patterns, e.g., `VertexStyle -> {Alternatives@@lis2 -> Blue}` when specifying options.

This is particularly convenient for setting different options for multiple subsets of vertices/edges. For example,

```
SeedRandom[1]
SA = SparseArray[_ :> RandomInteger[1], {10, 10}];
AdjacencyGraph[lis1, SA,
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexStyle -> {_ -> White, Alternatives @@ lis2 -> Blue,  "E" -> Black},
 VertexLabelStyle -> {Red, Alternatives @@ lis2 -> Directive[16, White, Bold, Italic]}, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> {Alternatives["C", "J"] -> "ConcaveHexagon"},
 VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]